# How to use _beforesave custom module check already exists or not

Tags: magento-1.9

Hi I have a Custom module While Saving database i need to check weater the data available in database or not

Can you please guide me how to check this?

```
public function saveAction()
        {

            $post_data=$this->getRequest()->getPost();


                if ($post_data) {

                    try {                   

                        $model = Mage::getModel("delivery/delivery")
                        ->addData($post_data)
                        ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam("id"))
                        ->save();
                        Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addSuccess(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Delivery was successfully saved"));
                        Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->setDeliveryData(false);

                        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam("back")) {
                            $this->_redirect("*/*/edit", array("id" => $model->getId()));
                            return;
                        }


                        $this->_redirect("*/*/");
                        return;
                    } 
                    catch (Exception $e) {
                        Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addError($e->getMessage());
                        Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->setDeliveryData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                        $this->_redirect("*/*/edit", array("id" => $this->getRequest()->getParam("id")));
                    return;
                    }

                }
                $this->_redirect("*/*/");
        }
```

Comment: Can you share save action's code, so I will guide you to check duplication

Comment: please check my update question

Comment: as per your code, if you are passing `id` as parameter then it will not create duplicate recored, it will just update existing entity with `id`

Comment: Also if you want to check duplication for particular field then let me know, like email, mobile etc.

Comment: Ya I want to check name and email

Answer (score 1):

Please try this,

```
public function saveAction()
        {

            $post_data=$this->getRequest()->getPost();


                if ($post_data) {
                    //check for duplicate------------[start]
                    $name = $post_data['name_field_name'];
                    $email = $post_data['email_field_name'];

                    $collection = Mage::getModel("delivery/delivery")
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('name_field_name_in_db',['eq' => $name]);
                    ->addFieldToFilter('email_field_name_in_db',['eq' => $email]);

                    if($this->getRequest()->getParam("id") != ''){
                        $collection->addFieldToFilter('id', ['neq' => $this->getRequest()->getParam("id")]);
                    }
                    //check for duplicate------------[end]

                    try {                   

                        if(!count($collection)){ 
                            $model = Mage::getModel("delivery/delivery")
                            ->addData($post_data)
                            ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam("id"))
                            ->save();
                            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addSuccess(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Delivery was successfully saved"));
                            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->setDeliveryData(false);

                            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam("back")) {
                                $this->_redirect("*/*/edit", array("id" => $model->getId()));
                                return;
                            }
                        }else {
                            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addError(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Name or email already exist"));

                            $this->_redirect("*/*/edit", array("id" => $this->getRequest()->getParam("id")));
                                return;
                        }

                        $this->_redirect("*/*/");
                        return;
                    } 
                    catch (Exception $e) {
                        Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addError($e->getMessage());
                        Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->setDeliveryData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                        $this->_redirect("*/*/edit", array("id" => $this->getRequest()->getParam("id")));
                    return;
                    }

                }
                $this->_redirect("*/*/");
        }
```